# MySql syntaxErrorException when manually building SQL query with AND or OR conditions

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am developing a simple web appilcation using JSP,Servlets and Mysql. I have table called annotations in Mysql database. I would like fetch only the records based on 'OR' and 'AND' from Mysql. But unfortunately I am getting a jdbc-Mysql Synatax exception. I'm composing the SQL query as below:

```
dbconnection=new dbconnection();
            connection=dbconnection.setConnection();
            Transcript_ID=request.getParameter("Transcript_ID");
            Condition_1=request.getParameter("Condition_1"); // Can be "OR" or "AND".
            Gene_Symbol=request.getParameter("Gene_Symbol"); 
            Condition_2=request.getParameter("Condition_2"); // Can be "OR" or "AND".
            Molecular_Function=request.getParameter("Molecular_Function");
            Condition_3=request.getParameter("Condition_3"); // Can be "OR" or "AND".
            Biological_Process=request.getParameter("Biological_Process");
            stmt=connection.createStatement();
            query="select * from annotations where ID='"+Transcript_ID+"','"+Condition_1+"',Gene_Symbol='"+Gene_Symbol+"','"+Condition_2+"',"+ "Molecular_Function='"+Molecular_Function+"','"+Condition_3+"',Biological_Process='"+Biological_Process+"'";
```

The error is I got in my console is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''OR',Gene_Symbol='tmx3','OR',Molecular_Function='','OR',Biological_Process=''' at line 1

Could anyone guide me where was the mistake in my sql syntax.

Comment: Aside from anything else, stop concatenating values to create SQL like that. Use a PreparedStatement with parameterized SQL, to avoid conversion issues, SQL injection attacks, and messy code. Next, dump out your full SQL before executing it - it'll make it much easier to see what's wrong at that point.

Comment: Please use PreparedStatement, this way of writing sql queries is Sql injection prone

Comment: Your missing AND, Or operator in Sql Query

Comment: You have commas in your SQL query where they don't belong.

Comment: Have a log statement to print your query and check it. Or use SQL tool/editor to run it to make sure that the query creation is correct.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel In MySQL workbench, when I type "SELECT * FROM annotations where Transcript_ID='' OR Gene_Symbol='tmx3' or Molecular_Function='';". It works fine. But in my sql query in java, it becomes like "SELECT * FROM annotations where Transcript_ID='' 'OR' Gene_Symbol='tmx3' 'OR' Molecular_Function='';" . I think this the reason. I dont know how to remove the single quotes in sql query in java

Comment: You should really print out query, because in the code in your question you have commas around your conditions (and extra quotes where they don't belong): `**,**'"+Condition_1+"'**,**`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel This is the query which I used in java servlet is query="select * from annotations where ID='"+Transcript_ID+"','"+Condition_1+"',Gene_Symbol='"+Gene_Symbol+"','"+Condition_2+"',"     + "Molecular_Function='"+Molecular_Function+"','"+Condition_3+"',Biological_Process='"+Biological_Process+"'";

Comment: Print out the **result** of that statement (that is the value of **`query`** after evaluation. You will notice that you have produced an invalid statement, just like MySQL tells you.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried printing out the result statement, but before it prints , the error was thrown.

Comment: I find that hard to believe: `query = "..."` is just a string assignment and itself doesn't send to the server; just add `System.out.println(query);` immediately after that assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove commas from where conditions

```
query="select * from annotations where ID='"+Transcript_ID+"' "+Condition_1+" Gene_Symbol='"+Gene_Symbol+"' "+Condition_2+" "+ "Molecular_Function='"+Molecular_Function+"' "+Condition_3+" Biological_Process='"+Biological_Process+"'";
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not substituting AND / OR junctions, but a comma instead.

please let us see the sql sentence producing code.

Comment: hi, Thanks. Do you mean the SQl query? If it is I have already pasted in the above query

Comment: COPY & PASTE THIS : `query="select * from annotations "                                    +
      " where   ID                  = '"  + Transcript_ID      + "' " +
  Condition_1 + " Gene_Symbol        = '"  + Gene_Symbol        + "' " + 
  Condition_2 + " Molecular_Function = '"  + Molecular_Function + "' " + 
  Condition_3 + " Biological_Process = '"  + Biological_Process + "' ";`

Answer (score 0):

Don't add "," in sql statement remove commas and add conditions like and/or or you can take like Gene_Symbol in('abc','cba') like this

Comment: The condition And/OR will be specified by the user. So I get the input and later pass tot he query. my problem is in my query the AND/OR is represented as 'AND' / 'OR' which throws error.